# how to apply carousel in cards reactjs

Tags: reactjs, npm, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am stuck with a problem, can anyone tell me how can I apply the carousel in cards, I did it but it's not working, below I share my whole carousel code please checkout and tell me how can I do it

> cards.js

This is the cards file where I used carousal in cards but it's not working

```
import React from "react";
import "./Cards.css";
import Card from "./Card";

const Cards = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>
        <b>Discover more features</b>
      </h1>

      <div className="row"></div>
      <div
        id="carouselExampleControls"
        class="carousel slide"
        data-ride="carousel"
      >
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item " style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-3">
                <Card />
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-3">
                <Card />
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-3">
                <Card />
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-3">
                <Card />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-3">
                <Card />
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-3">
                <Card />
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-3">
                <Card />
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-3">
                <Card />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a
          class="carousel-control-prev"
          href="#carouselExampleControls"
          role="button"
          data-slide="prev"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a
          class="carousel-control-next"
          href="#carouselExampleControls"
          role="button"
          data-slide="next"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cards;
```

Comment: Can you be specific about the not working part?

Comment: [This](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/) might help.

Comment: thanku sir , but i want to apply cards in carousel how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation of [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#example),

> The `.active` class needs to be added to one of the slides otherwise the carousel will not be visible.

You have missed adding the `.active` class to one of the `.carousal-items` slides of the carousel component.

No need to add the `display: flex;` property. The class `row` of bootstrap itself has a `display: flex;` property.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" style="background-color: black;" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly;">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly;">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly;">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>




  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanku for help sir ,but i want like this  carousel   https://www.skype.com/en/ please help me how can i do it

Comment: Try [this](https://www.codeply.com/go/EIOtI7nkP8/bootstrap-carousel-with-multiple-cards).